# jQuery ajax pass model as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, razor

I have a razor page containing a jQuery ajax function I would like to send the model as a parameter to.  I use $('form').serialize() in many places where it is the only way parameters are set.  However, here I want to pass three specific parameters.  The second two are working as expected but no matter what I do the model always comes through as null.  Can anyone point to me what I am doing wrong?

```
//modal button click events to update mailhandlers for selected accounts
$('#updateMailhandler').click(function () {
    //add the selected ids to the hidden control to pass values to controller
    var selectedIds = "";
    $('[name$=".selected"]').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            selectedIds = selectedIds + ',' + $.trim($(this).parent().parent().find('.accountid').text());
        }
    });
    selectedIds = selectedIds.substring(1);
    //retrieve selected mailhandlerid
    var mhid = $('#mailhandlerId').val();

    //execute the controller method
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMailhandler", "SendingReport")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { model: $('form').serialize(), selectedAccountString: selectedIds, mailhandlerId: mhid },
        type: 'POST'
    })
})
```

I have tried removing the dataType declaration.  I have tried wrapping $('form').serialize() in JSON.stringify and nothing is doing it.  Clearly this must be close as it finds the method, just that model is null!

Comment: Add declaration `UpdateMailhandler` action.

Comment: @Alexander the method exists and is called.  It just wasn't passing the model variable as expected.  I ended up splitting my html into small forms and just using data: $('form').serialize() ensuring that the controls that hold the values I am looking for have the exact same name as the variable name in the method.  It works that way and the model comes through as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and ended up storing the model in TempData and then retrieving it again in the action called by Ajax (in your case UpdateMailHandler).

If I remember correctly, this was because the mvc routing does not support passing complex types as route values. You can create a custom route to accept each property of your model as a parameter if they are simple types but it's much cleaner to just store the values in TempData.